# Why imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); and <application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" have different effect?

Tags: android, svg, imageview, android-hardware

I wonder why if I set

```
<application
   android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

using [svg-android](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android) i see no image (due to hw acceleration problem?), but if I set

```
imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

I can get it to work.

Does `View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE` disables the hw acceleration or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The direct answer to your question

> (Does `View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE` disables the hardware acceleration or
>   not?)

is YES.

It actually disable hardware acceleration, but only at a view level, i.e. hardware acceleration is disabled in `ImageView` in your case, while setting `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` will disable hardware acceleration for your whole application.

For more detailed, please refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html).